# What is the French phrase of "Do you expect me to believe that?!"

Tags: traduction, formulation-idiomatique

When I asked "You've heard of One Direction, right?", my pal answered "Nope.", so I wanted to react, surprised,

"What? Haha, do you expect me to believe that?! Have you any idea how hard it was for me to get their concert pass?!"

Does this make sense,

"Quoi? Tu t'attends vraiment à ce que je croie ça?!"

Answer (score 5):

C'est un peu littéral. Je dirais : "Tu veux vraiment me faire croire que..."

Answer (score 2):

I would choose these translations which sound good with the context :

**"C'est vrai ce mensonge?"**  which literally means "Is that lie true?"

or something like :

**"Tu te fiches de moi?"**

Answer (score 1):

While your phrasing is perfectly understandable, some idiomatic ways to express this idea (in a friendly tone) are:

> Tu as déjà entendu parler de One Direction, hein ?
>
> Non.
>
> Comment ça ?! **Allons, à d’autres !** {*or:*} **Prends-moi pour un idiot !** Si tu savais le mal que je me suis donné pour trouver des billets pour leur concert...

Comment: "Allons, à d'autres" is rather formal/old-fashioned though

Answer (score 0):

> Ouais, et tu comptes me faire gober ça ?